# Flutter result of matrix4.toString()

Tags: flutter

```
Matrix4 matrix = Matrix4(
   0, 0, 1, 0,
   -1, 0, 0, 0,
   0, -1, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 1
);

print(matrix);
```

The result of printing is below.

```
I/flutter (15723): [0] 0.0,-1.0,0.0,0.0
I/flutter (15723): [1] 0.0,0.0,-1.0,0.0
I/flutter (15723): [2] 1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
I/flutter (15723): [3] 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
```

Does the [0] of the log mean column[0] ?
or are row and column reversed on Initialization?

i'm using flutter v1.22.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your first question, the [`toString` method source code](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/vector_math/Matrix4/toString.html) displays

```dart
@override
String toString() => '[0] ${getRow(0)}\n[1] ${getRow(1)}\n'
    '[2] ${getRow(2)}\n[3] ${getRow(3)}\n';
```

So each number corresponds to its respective row index.

On your second question, the [class documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/vector_math/Matrix4-class.html) says:

> 4D Matrix. Values are stored in column major order.

The [Wikipedia page for column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) says:

> In row-major order, the consecutive elements of a row reside next to each other, whereas the same holds true for consecutive elements of a column in column-major order.

You can think of it as "row and column reversed", but it's just the unintuitive storing strategy.